# Popen in Python returning a different output when run from Cron (vs command line)

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm having a strange issue with my Python script.  When I run it through the command line `python /home/myname/myscriptname.py` it returns the correct values that I am expecting.

This is my cron command - `10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myname/myscriptname.py`

When run through cron, I get the following output (incorrect)-

```
('', None)
Module not enabled
```

When I run it in through the command line, I get the following (correct)-

```
The following people have the module enabled: 
person1
person2
person3
```

What gives?  I've tried calling out each command with the full path (no dice), and adding the following into the crontab -

`PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` with no change.  What else could the issue be?  When running the script as the same user who owns the crontab, it works correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, subprocess

command = '/usr/local/bin/drush --alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases @staging pml -y | /bin/grep -i dblog | /bin/grep -i enabled'


#Module Check
try:
   process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

   output2 = process.communicate()
   print output2
   if output2[0] == "":
      staging_return = "Module not enabled"
   else:
      staging_return = "The following people have the module enabled: \n" + output2[0]
   print staging_return

except Exception as E:
   print E
   print "Command failed"
```

EDIT -  Here is the output of os.environ in each environment -

This is the output of os.environ in cron -

```
{'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'SHLVL': '1', 'PWD': '/home/myuser', 'LOGNAME': 'myuser', 'USER': 'myuser', 'HOME': '/home/myuser', 'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin', '_': '/usr/bin/python'}
```

The output in the terminal is -

```
{'LESSOPEN': '||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s', 'CVS_RSH': 'ssh', 'LOGNAME': 'myuser', 'USER': 'myuser', 'QTDIR': '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3', 'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'SHLVL': '2', 'G_BROKEN_FILENAMES': '1', 'HISTSIZE': '1000', 'SUDO_USER': 'myuser', 'HOME': '/home/myuser', 'USERNAME': 'root', 'SUDO_UID': '860', '_': '/usr/bin/python', 'SUDO_COMMAND': '/bin/su', 'SUDO_GID': '860', 'HOSTNAME': 'MYHOSTNAME', 'PWD': '/home/myuser', 'MAIL': '/var/spool/mail/myuser',
```

Comment: Could this be because cron runs your script as root instead of a local user? What is the output if you sudo the script from the commandline?

Comment: You might try switching the shell used: add `executable='/bin/bash'` to your `Popen` call because default cron shell is `sh`. Also, check `env` for the user when logged in versus when the script is running. Could be other random stuff getting set (sometimes `PYTHONPATH`, for instance).

Comment: The cron job is not set to the root user, and when I try to run it as root it fails (it cant ssh).  Since it is connecting to the other servers I'm pretty sure that is working.

Adding executable='/bin/bash' did not change the behavior of the Popen call.

Comment: I have edited the original question to contain the variables in each environment

Comment: Could it be that you have some environment variables (other than Path) defined for the user that have an influence on the above command? Could you try: . '~/.bashrc; /usr/local/bin/drush --alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases @staging pml -y | /bin/grep -i dblog | /bin/grep -i enabled'

Comment: Also could you capture the stderr and print it too?

Comment: This is what I see after adding those two suggestions - `done
('', '')
Module not enabled`

Comment: Could this possibly be caused by the the unblocking aspect of Popen?  This whole command usually takes around 3 minutes to run through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found what the issues were.

There were two issues.  The first issue was with the command variable -

`command = '/usr/local/bin/drush --alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases @staging pml -y | /bin/grep -i dblog | /bin/grep -i enabled'`

This command needs to be split into a list, and then passed into Popen as a list instead of as one large command.  My command variable turned into this -

`command = ['/usr/local/bin/drush', '--alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases', '@staging', 'pml', '-y']` (do the same for the other piped statements as well).

After making this change, my command was hanging on process.communicate.  In order to fix that issue, I had to add a stdin argument to my Popen call.  My new Popen call with this argument passed in looked like this -

`process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` (Got rid of the shell=True since I am not piping statements in one long bash command anymore.

Instead of piping outputs from one to another, I did the following -

```
command2 = ['/bin/grep', '-i', 'dblog']
command3 = ['/bin/grep', '-i', 'enabled']
process2 = subprocess.Popen(command2, stdin=process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process3 = subprocess.Popen(command3, stdin=process2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```